# Как избавится от Exception при попытке добавления дубликатов с UNIQUE полями?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE recruiter (
        nickname TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        url_account TEXT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (nickname)
);

CREATE TABLE proposal (
        header TEXT NOT NULL,
        url_proposal TEXT NOT NULL,
        time_addition TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        nickname TEXT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (url_proposal, header),
        FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES recruiter (nickname)
);
```

Я добавляю данные в вторую, и как видно есть 2 поля дубликаты которых я не хочу хранить: `UNIQUE (url_proposal, header)`. Но иногда дубликаты все же попадаются, и вылетает :

```
PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "proposal_url_proposal_header_key"
```

Для добавления я использую такой скрипт:

```
INSERT INTO proposal (
        header, 
        url_proposal, 
        time_addition, 
        nickname) 

VALUES ((?), (?), (?), (?))
```

Помогите пожалуйста модифицировать скрипт так что бы в случае если в таблице найден дубликат по соответствующим полям, добавления просто не происходило без `Exception`. Спасибо.

Comment: Обработка исключений try catch finally

Comment: Определитесь, что требуется в случае обнаружения дубликата - проигнорировать новые данные или заменить старые новыми. В любом случае - можете обработать ошибку, как указано выше, или использовать `ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо поменять скрипт на:

```
CREATE TABLE recruiter (
        nickname TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        url_account TEXT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (nickname) on conflict ignore //ключ здесь
);
```